# How to write csv file and download in browser?

Tags: laravel-5

In laravel 5.7 app I need to write csv file and download in in browsers download function using method :

\Response::download(

I try to upload it to tmp directory and checking value I see

```
$sys_get_temp_dir= sys_get_temp_dir();
```

line above has /tmp value

Next I save it as :

```
$dest_csv_file= $sys_get_temp_dir . '/box_rooms_'.time().'.csv';
$header = ["Id",... ];

$fp = fopen($dest_csv_file, "w");

fputcsv($fp, $header);

foreach ($storageSpacesCollection as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}

fclose($fp);
```

But searching on my local ubuntu 18(on server I also have ubuntu) I found generated file as

```
/tmp/systemd-private-6a9ea6844b9c4c94883d23e4fb3e2215-apache2.service-shqCeo/tmp/box_rooms_1576324869.csv
```

That was very strange, as I do not know how read it from tmp path. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you need to pass Content-Type properly**

```
$filePath= public_path(). "/upload/example.doc";
$headersContent = array('Content-Type: application/pdf',);
return Response::download($filePath, 'example.doc', $headersContent)
```

Comment: A little explanation of what was wrong and what you changed to make it work would be nice